# TFS WorkItemChangedEvent fires twice

Tags: c#, events

I have a TFS2012 plugin that uses the

> public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent()

to get the WorkItemChangedEvent. It doesn't do much, it just adds the WorkItemChangedEvent into a Message Queue, so that I can fetch it with a different service later on.

For some reason the event always fires twice for every work item I change and adds the event twice to my queue.

Any idea why?

The code I use:

```
    public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(
        TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext,
        NotificationType notificationType, object notificationEventArgs,
        out int statusCode, out string statusMessage, out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
    {
        statusCode = 0;
        properties = null;
        statusMessage = String.Empty;

        try
        {
            if (notificationType == NotificationType.Notification && notificationEventArgs is WorkItemChangedEvent)
            {
                var ev = notificationEventArgs as WorkItemChangedEvent;
                const string queueName = ".\\private$\\tfs";
                var msgQueue = new MessageQueue(queueName);
                var msg = new Message(ev);
                msgQueue.Send(msg, MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
                Log.Debug(string.Format("Added event for work item #{0} to queue", ev.WorkItemTitle));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal("Error", ex);
            return EventNotificationStatus.ActionDenied;
        }

        return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
    }
```

Comment: It's bound to have different properties. Have you examined the event to see what's different about them?

Comment: @PreetSangha: I've checked the body of the two queue messages that got added. They are absolute identically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(as always, minutes after I've asked the question, I get the right idea)

Today I learned:
A subfolder in the plugin directory is not enough to disable a plugin. I made a backup of my old automation in an "old" folder, but it still loaded it.